# Error "Invalid resource directory name" when trying to create android app with phonegap in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I followed the tutorial [here](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse) but when I create the project in Eclipse, i get an error "invalid resource directory name. Resource: "drawable-hdpi" path "/HelloAndroid/res" type "Android AAPT Problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong platform set. Right click on the Project name in Eclipse and go to properties and then click on Android and select at least Android 1.6.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. It turned out that I copied xml **files** from phonegap's `xml` folder to the project's `res` folder, not the whole `xml` folder.

So in the project's folder structure should go like this:

```
res/xml/phonegap.xml
res/xml/plugins.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

had the issue when I forgot to add xml file inside the xml folder