# Error: Invalid Resource directory name in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a Sudoku Android app but I am getting a error under strings.xml. This is the line of code: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and this is the error: Invalid Resource directory name. I am new at Android development and have never seen this error.

Thanks in advance, Zizeeo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error “Invalid resource directory name” when trying to create android app with phonegap in eclipse.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197547/error-invalid-resource-directory-name-when-trying-to-create-android-app-with-ph)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It turned out that I copied xml **files** from phonegap's `xml` folder to the project's `res` folder, not the whole `xml` folder.

So in the project's folder the structure should go like this:

```
res/xml/phonegap.xml
res/xml/plugins.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at lease include

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    </resources>
```

Comment: I have that. Here is what I have: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <resources>

  <color name="background">3500ffff</color>
  <string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
  <string name="main_title">Android_Sudoku</string>
  <string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
  <string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
  <string name="about_label">About</string>
  <string name="exit_label">Exit</string>


 </resources>'

Comment: the color number needs to be preceded by a # '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="background">#3500ffff</color>
 <string
  name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
 <string
  name="main_title">Android_Sudoku</string>
 <string
  name="continue_label">Continue</string>
 <string
  name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
 <string
  name="about_label">About</string>
 <string
  name="exit_label">Exit</string>
</resources>'

Comment: Yes, I see I need that but I am still getting the same error.